# How to insert a video or gif in PowerBI through a link?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a dashboard presentation and I'm required to put key visuals on my Powerbi dashboard. Those key visuals are short mp4 videos and gifs. My data source is an excel file that indicates the link of the key visual. Below is a screenshot of my sample data source: [Sample Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndaVv.png)

I have a slicer on my dashboard that selects different contents. So for example I'd like to select this ad then it should show this specific key visual using the link.
[Sample Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VE39.png)

I just need to show the video/gif even without the audio

Thanks!

I tried external visuals available from powerbi. Such as Video by cloudscope and ImageGrid. But it cant recognize the link, so what do you suggest?